# On creation of contact from account (Primary contact),last name gets auto filled - MS crm 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have created contact from account(primary contact) through quick create form,if I am creating contact second time on same account(Primary contact), "Last name" field filled as selected contact's First Name+ Last Name in Quick create form.

can anyone tell me what could be the reason?

any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Amar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because CRM sees the `primarycontactid` value as more of a user trying to find a `contact` which is also the natural flow of things in CRM. You create an account, either you assign a known primary contact or enter a search term which does not resolve to an existing contact, in which case it makes a lot of sense to auto-map the lookup search term to the last name on the contact.

Although the behavior makes much more sense if the `lastname` was pre-populated with the look up search term if the contact was non-existent, the downside effect of it overweighs the actual functionality, especially considering the natural flow of things.